# CMD + space not working in the first try

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, spotlight

I'm having troubles with Spotlight.

1. <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> isn't working in the first try, but when I try it again it does work. After few minutes I need to do it twice again for it to pop.
2. I don't see app result anymore. I tried to add it to the privacy section in the spotlight setting, than remove it so it will be re-indexed. It didn't work.

Somehow I think they tied together. I have the latest OS (macOS High Sierra)

Appreciate the help.

Since I got an answer for the first one, I'll post here [the solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7356551?start=0&tstart=0) for the second one. Just add the whole computer (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) to the privacy in the spotlight settings - then remove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i saw this on a user's machine lately.  it was acting very strangely with a couple command keys.

the solution here was to go to **keyboard** preference pane and clear out all shortcuts and restore defaults for each section.  it seems an app this user installed was grabbing the key-combo for its own purposes, and once removing the customizing it worked well.

it might be this simple in your case.

Comment: It may have solved the first one. Thanks! Still couldn't find solution for the second one.

Comment: as far as part 2" . you don't see app results meaning you see matches on the hard drive for files, but not for applications on there?    there is a checkbox in spotlight preference pane for show/don't show applications in search results .

Answer (score 11):

Per this blog post, if you are connected to an external monitor(s) changing the desktop resolution to something else and back worked for me. Spotlight was working the whole time just off the screensomewhere:

https://blog.pcrisk.com/mac/12708-spotlight-search-not-working-on-mac-how-to-fix

Comment: It would be best for you to, at least, summarize what you are linking to (more than you have) so that if the page vanishes we still have a usable answer

Comment: This was it for me! I couldn't figure out how to change the resolution, so I went from mirrored display to not-mirrored (Cmd-fn-dimmer) and got my spotlight back. Then I went back to mirrored and it was there again.

Comment: This worked for me also, i just changed the screen rotation, and the changed it back and it started working again.

Comment: I just clicked on external monitor and upvoted this answer. It started working for me xD

Comment: In case it helps someone: This was the problem for me as well, but changing resolutions didn't solve it. Instead I used a keyboard shortcut to maximize Spotlight while I knew it was active (even though I couldn't see it), then dragged it to the desired location.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

∙ **Step 1**:

Open **System Preferences/Keyboard** and select **Keyboard Shortcuts**

Click **Spotlight** on the left. Make sure the shortcuts are correct. If not, click: **Restore Defaults**.

∙ **Step 2**:

How to reset NVRAM or PRAM on Mac:

**Apple Support**: https://support.apple.com/ht204063

or

**YouTube tutorial**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPzu7n_q6ag

Note: For me it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its not <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>Space</kbd> at the same time. Press and hold <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> and then press <kbd>Space</kbd>. It should bring you the spotlight

Answer (score 0):

After reading @neuralstatic's answer I quit Karabiner-Elements and it fixed the problem.

Then I relaunched it and <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> still works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Catalina today with Adobe Ill 25. I deactivated shortcuts for both spotlight and Siri. It works now.